# Unable to trash folder: Permission denied from /opt directory

Tags: permissions, delete, trash

I got one minor error while trashing my folder. When I tried to delete folder from `/opt` directory it did show one error like `dhiva: Unable to trash file: Permission denied`. I tried to delete through the terminal using this comment

```
dhivahar@dhivahar-PVM900M:~$ sudo rm /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/dhiva
```

But it failed to delete. I got this error from terminal

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/dhiva’: Is a directory
```

I can't edit any files from these directories. I am new for Ubuntu :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/dhiva
```

Comment: its work.. great... thank so much.. thank you so much for quick response...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo rm -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/dhiva
```

It should work too.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of the accepted answer or the question.